# How to write a custom solution using a python package, modules etc

Tags: python

I am writing a packacge foobar which consists of the modules alice, bob, charles and david.

From my understanding of Python packages and modules, this means I will create a folder foobar, with the following subdirectories and files (please correct if I am wrong)

```
foobar/
  __init__.py
  alice/alice.py
  bob/bob.py
  charles/charles.py
  david/david.py
```

The package should be executable, so that in addition to making the modules alice, bob etc available as 'libraries', I should also be able to use foobar in a script like this:

python foobar --args=someargs

**Question1:**

Can a package be made executable and used in a script like I described above?

**Question 2**

The various modules will use code that I want to refactor into a common library. Does that mean creating a new sub directory 'foobar/common' and placing common.py in that folder?

**Question 3**

How will the modules foo import the common module ?
Is it 'from foobar import common' or can I not use this since these modules are part of the package?

**Question 4**

I want to add logic for when the foobar package is being used in a script (assuming this can be done - I have only seen it done for modules)

The code used is something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  dosomething()
```

where (in which file) would I put this logic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a package be made executable and
>   used in a script like I described
>   above?

**Q1 and Q4**. Yes, place your:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  dosomething()
```

in `foobar/__init__.py`

> **Q2** The various modules will use code that
>   I want to refactor into a common
>   library. Does that mean creating a new
>   sub directory 'foobar/common' and
>   placing common.py in that folder?

No, you have to create `foobar/common.py`, not `foobar/common/common.py`. The same is true for all of your modules. Thus the right structure is:

```
foobar/
  __init__.py
  alice.py
  bob.py
  charles.py
  common.py
  david.py
```

Doing what you do you're creating package `foobar`, subpackage `alice` and module `alice` in it, etc. That is not what you want as I understand. Furthermore it will not work at all, since a directory becomes a Python package if it contains `__init__.py` in it, and you haven't created them in your subdirectories.

> **Q3** How will the modules foo import the
>   common module ? Is it `from foobar
>   import common`

That's right. You can also simply use `import common` however it can cause a conflict if your library will be used in a project that has it's own module/package named `common`. So I prefer to use fully-qualified module names.

Comment: Thanks - this is all I needed to know (I love this site!)

Comment: Can you take a look at this other question too pls, if you have the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882308/spawning-a-thread-in-python